# 'module' object is not callable but I've already imported the correct package

Tags: python, screen-scraping, reddit

I tried to do some scraping on reddit, and follow the instructions, however, the same code got some problem:

```
import praw
reddit = praw.reddit(client_id ='****',
                    client_secret='*****',
                    username='***',
                    password='*****',
                    user_agent='prawtest1'
                    )
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('python')

hot_python = subreddit.hot(limit=5)
for submission in hot_python:
    print(submission)

the result is:
'--> 7                     user_agent='prawtest1'
      8                     )
      9 subreddit = reddit.subreddit('python')
```

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I hided my personal data, but they're correct so don't worry if there's anything wrong with them.

Comment: Please show the full error traceback!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you might have just lowercased your method call by mistake -
 https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html

Try

```
 reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id ='****',
                client_secret='*****',
                username='***',
                password='*****',
                user_agent='prawtest1'
                )
```